# Permission issues on temporary file creation running LibreOffice soffice.exe from IIS AppPool

Tags: iis, libreoffice

I'm running soffice.exe from an IIS site with AppPool identity to convert a docx to pdf.

Somehow, it tries to create files in C:/Windows/LibreOffice, which causes an access error.
What could cause this behavior?

This is the code part:

```
string libreOfficePath = @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe";
string docxPath = @"D:\docs\abc.docx";
string pdfOutputPath = @"D:\docs\out";
string logPath = @"D:\docs\logs";

string arguments = "--headless --convert-to pdf " + docxPath + " --outdir " + pdfOutputPath;

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = libreOfficePath,
    Arguments = arguments,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program"
};
```

These are my settings:
[image: pic1]
I've given the app pool permissions for these folders.

If I set the app pool identity to localsystem, the command does the job and creates the pdf.

If I set to apppool identity, the process tries to create temp files in C:/Windows/LibreOffice, which obviously fails.

App monitor logs this:
[image: pic2]

This is the command line it gets:

```
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" "--headless" "--convert-to" "pdf" "D:\docs\abc.docx" "--outdir" "D:\docs\out" "-env:OOO_CWD=2C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program"
```

Comment: @LexLi Helpful comment. Thank you very much. True spirit of SO.

Comment: If you expect something more, consider these: 1) "I've given the app pool permissions for these folders" so what exactly are the permissions you gave? And NTFS requires permissions to be granted to accounts, and "the app pool" isn't an account, right? 2) "it tries to create files in C:/Windows/LibreOffice" isn't surprising. Web apps are not only running under application pool identity, but also in system session (aka session 0), so the settings you give to your account (and your user session) won't be usually honored there by the web app. But overall, basic NTFS rules apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple hundred attempts, specifying the folder with:

```
-env:UserInstallation=
```

solved the issue.